# Rounding amount in javascript

Tags: numbers, rounding

I'm trying to round the amount in my form's total, tried several methods provided in different threads but none worked for me.

my form url is http://indushospital.org.pk/qurbani/

The amount shown in total is multiplied with 2.5% additional charges due to which its showing the amount like USD 186.63372, I want to show it like 186.64 Or simply 187.

The additional charges formula is mentioned below:

```
function getAmountPlusCharges(amount) {
    // additionalCharges would result here '250' when '20000' is passed as amount.
    var additionalCharges = (amount * 2.564) / 100; 
    return additionalCharges + amount;
```

Please help, I
'm not familiar with java functions at all

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Please help, I 'm not familiar with java functions at all" --- Java is *not* JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry @Amadan my bad :) *JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use Math.round, then you can use to fixed to make sure its always 2 decimal places.

```
function getAmountPlusCharges(amount) {

    return (Math.round(amount * 102.564 ) / 100).toFixed(2);

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @brianxautumn. This method worked like a charm. :)